# Normal lines to surfaces or planes in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

How do I make the normal line to a plane actually look perpendicular?

```
cc = Plot3D[2 x + y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}]

bb = ParametricPlot3D[{2 t, t, -t}, {t, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick]

Show[cc, bb]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The line doesn't look even close to perpendicular to the plane.

Answer (score 16):

The reason is that the three axes use different scales by default to avoid extreme elongation in case the range of one axis is much larger than the others.

Use

```
Show[cc, bb, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]