# Draw a vector with mathematica

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

at the risk of being trivial I would like to draw the vector $\vec{AB}$ where $A$ an d $B$ have the  coordinates  $(1,1,1)$ and (1,-1,2) respectively.

Comment: Do you mean `Arrow[{{1,1,1},{1,-1,2}}]`?

Comment: `Graphics3D[Arrow[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 2}}]]`

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Nikie's comment...

```
Graphics3D[Arrow[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 2}}], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Arrow is a symbolic graphics primitive.  Graphics3D is a function to draw graphics primitives.

Comment: Thank you so much for yours help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use all of [Three‐Dimensional Graphics Primitives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ThreeDimensionalGraphicsPrimitives.html) like so;

```
a = {1, 1, 1};
b = {1, -1, 2};
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{a, b}]}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

If useful, WA also can process this information, **check the parametric info**;

[image]

And there is a **verry nice Reference** on this Site:

[Plot points, line and plane in one 3D plot [closed]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34038/plot-points-line-and-plane-in-one-3d-plot)