# Manipulate through Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, manipulate

Inspired in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34038/plot-points-line-and-plane-in-one-3d-plot). I am attempting to run a Manipulate through a 3d Graphic. This is the code that I am trying:

```
a1 = ContourPlot3D[
  5 x - 4 y - 9 z == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red]];
g[t_] := {t, t/2, t/3};
b1 = ParametricPlot3D[g[t], {t, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]];
c1[x_] = Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{0, 0, 0}], Green, 
   Point[{x, -1, 1}]}];
Manipulate[
Show[a1, b1, c1[x], 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

But this does not produce the desire output, and insetad yields 3 separate 3 plots that are static. Is there a better way to use manipulate to "move" a point in a 3D plot? Thanks!

Comment: I only see a single composite plot. What version of Mathematica are you using? `a1` and `b1` are not dependent on `x` and will not be affected by the `Manipulate` control. `c1` does not vary much in the specified range. Change the control to `{{x, 0}, -10, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}` to see greater movement.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. I am running in 12.0 now, and it renders well. I was running it in a different version earlier and it would give me 3 separate plots, I can update it tomorrow!